# How to get correct column and row index?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Given a table like:

```
<table id="table-data">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>
        <input class="form-control column_data" type="text" autofocus placeholder="Title" name="Name"  value="">
      </th>
      <th>
        <input class="form-control column_data" type="text" autofocus placeholder="Title" name="Name"  value="">
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="tr_clone">
      <td><input class="form-control row_data" type="text" autofocus placeholder="data" name="who" value=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr_clone">
      <td><input class="form-control row_data" type="text" autofocus placeholder="data" name="who" value=""></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

How can I save the column `th input` value with its relative `row input data`?

I tried with proving a class but it's not getting me anywhere:

```
$('#saveTable').on("click", function() {
  var myTableArray = $("table th input").val();
  var $this = $(this);
  var myIndex = 0;
    $("table th input").each(function() {
    $(this).attr("data-index", "_" + myIndex);
    var thisLabelData = $(this).attr("data-index");
    $("table tbody input").each(function() {
        console.log(thisLabelData);
      if(!$(this).hasClass(thisLabelData)) {
        $(this).addClass(thisLabelData);
      }
    });
    //$this.push(myTableArray);
    myIndex++;
  });
  //console.log(myTableArray);
});
```

[jsFiddle playground](http://jsfiddle.net/Crw2C/1536/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this out and let me know

```js
$('#saveTable').on("click", function() {
 
   var results={};
   $('thead input').each(function(){
    results[$(this).val()] = [];
   });
   
   var resultsKeys = Object.keys(results);
   
   $('tbody input').each(function(){
    var colIndex = $(this).parent().index();
   
    var rowIndex = $(this).closest('tr').index();
    
    results[resultsKeys[colIndex-1]]
    .push("(" + (colIndex-1) + " " + rowIndex + ") -> " + 
    ($(this).val() !== '' ? $(this).val() : "0"));
   });
   
   console.log(results);
   
 
});


    $('#table-data input').on("change", function() {
      $(this).attr("value", $(this).attr("value"));
    });

    $(".table-striped tbody tr th input").each(function(){
      $(this).addClass("column_data");
    });

    $("#addTr").on('click', function() {
      var $tr    = $('tbody tr.tr_clone');
      var $clone = $tr.clone();
      $clone.find(':text').val('');
      $tr.after($clone);
      $(".table-striped tbody tr td input").each(function(){
        $(this).addClass("row_data");
      });
    });

    $("#addTd").on("click", function(){
      $(".table-striped thead tr").append('<th><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary removeColumn btn-block">Delete column</button><br><input class="form-control" type="text" autofocus placeholder="Title" name="Name"></th>');
      $(".table-striped tbody tr").append('</td> <td><input type="text" placeholder="data" name="datepicker_end" class="form-control"></td>');
      $(document).find("thead th input").each(function(){
        $(this).addClass("column_data");
      });
      $(".table-striped tbody tr td input").each(function(){
        $(this).addClass("row_data");
      });
    });
    
        $(document).on("click", ".removeRow", function(){
     $(this).parent().parent()
      $(this).parent().parent().remove();
    });

    $(document).on("click", ".removeColumn", function(){
      var index = $(this).parent().index() + 1;
      $(this).closest("table").find("td:nth-child(" + index + ")").remove();
      $(this).parent().remove();
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <hr>
      <h3>Insert your data</h3>
      <button id="addTd" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
        Add Column
      </button>
      <button id="addTr" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
        Add Row
      </button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="saveTable">Save table</button>
      <hr>
     <div class="table-responsive">
      <table id="table-data" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary removeColumn btn-block">Delete column</button>
              <br>
              <input class="form-control column_data" type="text" autofocus placeholder="Title" name="Name"  value="">
            </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr class="tr_clone">
            <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary removeRow">Delete row</button></td>
            <td><input class="form-control row_data" type="text" autofocus placeholder="data" name="who" value=""></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
     </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: this is perfect! Thanks a lot

Comment: @rob.m; Finally!! :)

Comment: haha yes indeed, been hours on it. Thank you very much, will accept it in a minute

Comment: maybe add this same answer to the other question too

Comment: really tempted lol, but no, it'd feel like cheating, would you consider deleting the other question so people with similar problem have more chances of finding this one? ;)

Comment: i tried.. but I can't. You should delete your answer first maybe

Comment: one last important bit would be to rebuild a table from the json, since our json could be multi dimensional, see https://jsfiddle.net/qpu3cn5u/103/

Comment: @rob.m maybe post a new question since this is a somewhat related but different procedure

Comment: superb thanks man, one last bit i'm trying to remove the indicators and only leaving  `results[resultsKeys[colIndex-1]].push(($(this).val() !== '' ? $(this).val() : "Null"));` but i get `Cannot read property 'push' of undefined`

Comment: @rob.m what do you mean by *indicators*? oh right, hold on

Comment: you've added -> and row and column number.. while I only need the correct values into the json

Comment: also try to insert a column and rows without to touch any input, it won't work https://jsfiddle.net/fbh0o67o/93/

Comment: it only works when we add ONE column and ONE row or if we leave it as when it loads, but if we add more than ONE it breaks for some reasons

Comment: look, I noticed the problem is you cannot allow repeated values in the headers, or It will break, since it is using `results[$(this).val()] = [];` to create the arrays. I'll leave that to you, good luck

Comment: i think i resolved it   by doing a check if empty or not for eah th and td input  `$('thead input').each(function(){
        if($(this).val() == "") {
         return;
        } else {
         results[$(this).val()] = [];
        }
       });

       $('tbody input').each(function(){

 if($(this).val() == "") {
         return;
        } else {
         results[resultsKeys[colIndex-1]].push($(this).val());
        }
       });`