# How to rebuild a table from a json?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

The following is almost working:

```
var data = [{"Mamma":["Papa","Nonna"],"Hello":["Bye","Yes"]}];

var colHeader = Object.keys(data[0]);

for(var i=0; i<colHeader.length; i++) {
    $('table thead tr').append('<td>' + colHeader[i] + '</td>');
}

for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
    $('table tbody').append('<tr></tr>')
    for(var j= 0; j<colHeader.length; j++){
    $('table tbody tr').last().append('<td>' + data[i][colHeader[j]] + '</td>');
  }
}
```

But i get the table with two values in a td as per the image below

[image]

[Here it is a jsFIddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qpu3cn5u/103/)

Comment: are there always going to be two elements per column in `tbody`? or is `[{"Mamma":["Papa","Nonna", "Could", "Be"],"Hello":["Bye","Yes", "Maybe"]}];` a valid input?

Comment: there could be even more than 2 rows @Scaramouche

Comment: @Scaramouche you've helped me today, basically we will get the value from the json we create with your answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/49613748/1018804

Comment: @Scaramouche this is the complete jsfiddle to play with https://jsfiddle.net/fbh0o67o/8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to also loop object values which are arrays and append then by index.

```js
var data = [{"Mamma": ["Papa", "Nonna"],"Hello": ["Bye", "Yes"]}];

data.forEach(obj => {
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
    $('thead').append($('<th>').text(key));

    obj[key].forEach((e, i) => {
      if(!$("tbody tr:eq("+i+")").length) $("<tr>").appendTo($("tbody"));
      $("tbody tr:eq(" + i + ")").append($('<td>').text(e))
    })
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead></thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Excellent thanks a lot. One last bit if I might please, see the json format we set in a variable? How can I convert the json created here https://jsfiddle.net/fbh0o67o/16/ into that format?

Comment: Show me in a example what json do you get and what is desired output.

Comment: see this example, I am building a table dynamically and i console.log the result when I hit the save button, that would also trigger the rebuilding of the table https://jsfiddle.net/fbh0o67o/26/

Comment: basically it generates a json like this `[{
  "Mamma": [
    "[Papa]",
    "[Nonna]"
  ],
  "Hello": [
    "[Bye]",
    "[Yes]"
  ]
}]
(index):91 [{
  "Mamma": [
    "[Papa]",
    "[Nonna]"
  ],
  "Hello": [
    "[Bye]",
    "[Yes]"
  ]
}]`

Comment: That is invalid data.

Comment: thought something was wrong with it, so how can I adjust it in order to come out as valid? https://jsfiddle.net/fbh0o67o/27/

Comment: almost there but the rebuild is getting me an error https://jsfiddle.net/fbh0o67o/29/

Answer (score 1):

Please try it with the sample in this snippet and let me know if it is the expected output.

```js
var data = [{"Hello": ["Bye", "", "", "", "", ""],"h2": ["", "", "", "c", "", "d"]}];

var outerIndex = 0;
$.each(data[0],(key, arr) => {
    $('thead').append($('<th>').text(key));

    data[0][key].forEach((e, i) => {
      if(!$("tbody tr:eq("+i+")").length)
        $("<tr>").appendTo($("tbody"));
        var colIndex = $("tbody tr:eq(" + i + ")").children('td').length;
        while(colIndex++ !== outerIndex){
          $("tbody tr:eq(" + i + ")").append('<td>');
        }
                
      $("tbody tr:eq(" + i + ")").append($('<td>').text(e))
    })
    outerIndex++
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead></thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: yes it is perfect, now basically i need to join both, the building table bit and the rebuild, it is almost working, but i am having an error in console when it tries to rebuild the table from the generated json https://jsfiddle.net/fbh0o67o/50/

Comment: @rob.m dunno what you mean by *building table bit and the rebuild*, are you trying to build a json and then rebuild an identical table to the one you have from that json?

Comment: yes exactly, because in reality I will send the json to the database and then call it on page load, the table building tool will be in the cms, while the rebuild table bit will be on a page

Comment: @rob.m I saw someone already pointed out the problem was you were calling `forEach` on a string

Comment: yes saw that, trying to fix it, it is almost working, just not printing all the values https://jsfiddle.net/fbh0o67o/65/

Comment: @rob.m, I just tried your fiddle with an input and it came out kinda broken, maybe it is not intended as a valid input, maybe it is, please check it out, it is the one in my updated answer, hope it helps

Comment: what do you mean with an input??

Comment: why would someone fill an empty table?

Comment: @rob.m; I mean with a certain sample as input, it's this one `[{"Hello": ["Bye", "", "", "", "", ""],"h2": ["", "", "", "c", "", "d"]}]`, it does not output a *proper* table, unless it's an invalid input, in which case you have nothing to worry about

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168071/discussion-between-rob-m-and-scaramouche).

Comment: @rob.m again, for some reason this sub domain: *https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168071/discussion-between-rob-m-and-scaramouche* is not getting along with the proxy I'm behind, good luck

Comment: actually i tried it https://jsfiddle.net/fbh0o67o/75/
i added few columns and roes, and then just fill one input
and it breaks
what would you suggest to do?
i find it strange that someone will print an empty table, maybe I should auto fill with a "null" stirng or "0" ?
or what would you do?

Comment: try my answer's code for that part, if that does not work, just fill them with `""`

Comment: yes I saw it how you've resolved it, yet I am filling the json while generating the table so it is the other bit of code we should add empty values if inputs are empty, i am using your code for that

Comment: `$('#saveTable').on("click", function() {

       var results={};
       $('thead input').each(function(){
        results[$(this).val()] = [];
       });

       var resultsKeys = Object.keys(results);

       $('tbody input').each(function(){
        var colIndex = $(this).parent().index();

        var rowIndex = $(this).closest('tr').index();

        results[resultsKeys[colIndex-1]].push($(this).val());
       });


       rebuild(results);

    });`

Comment: trying this with no luck `if ($(this).val() != "") {
          results[resultsKeys[colIndex-1]].push($(this).val());      
        } else {
          results[resultsKeys[colIndex-1]].push($(this).val("0"));        
        }`